# Can functions change members of a const struct parameter?

Tags: c

I'm trying to work with the Vimba SDK (specifically C version) and am confused about there context/usage of alloc and announce, specifically this function signature (I'm mostly asking about the last 6 lines, but am providing the other ones for context):

```
// Method:      VmbFrameAnnounce()
//
// Purpose:     Announce frames to the API that may be queued for frame capturing later.
//
// Parameters:
//
//  [in ]  const VmbHandle_t    cameraHandle    Handle for a camera
//  [in ]  const VmbFrame_t*    pFrame          Frame buffer to announce
//  [in ]  VmbUint32_t          sizeofFrame     Size of the frame structure
//
// Returns:
//
//  - VmbErrorSuccess:       If no error
//  - VmbErrorApiNotStarted: VmbStartup() was not called before the current command
//  - VmbErrorBadHandle:     The given camera handle is not valid
//  - VmbErrorBadParameter:  The given frame pointer is not valid or "sizeofFrame" is 0
//  - VmbErrorStructSize:    The given struct size is not valid for this version of the API
//
// Details:     Allows some preparation for frames like DMA preparation depending on the transport layer.
//              The order in which the frames are announced is not taken into consideration by the API.
//              The method can be used to annouce a previously allocated frame buffer to the transport layer.
//              Alternatively, in case "pFrame->buffer" points to NULL, the method will allocate and announce 
//              a new buffer. In this case "pFrame->buffer" contains the allocated buffer address on return.
//
IMEXPORTC VmbError_t VMB_CALL VmbFrameAnnounce ( const VmbHandle_t   cameraHandle,
                                                 const VmbFrame_t*   pFrame,
                                                 VmbUint32_t         sizeofFrame );
```

VmbFrame (a struct containing some values and a void-pointer buffer) is passed as const yet the according to the description the function still will change the pointer under some circumstances. So what does const even do then?

**Edit:**
Some more context. The relevant struct looks like this (we're mainly interested in the first two members):

```
typedef struct
{
    //----- In -----
    void*               buffer;             // Comprises image and ancillary data
    VmbUint32_t         bufferSize;         // Size of the data buffer

    void*               context[4];         // 4 void pointers that can be employed by the user (e.g. for storing handles)

    //----- Out -----
    VmbFrameStatus_t    receiveStatus;      // Resulting status of the receive operation
    VmbFrameFlags_t     receiveFlags;       // Flags indicating which additional frame information is available

    VmbUint32_t         imageSize;          // Size of the image data inside the data buffer
    VmbUint32_t         ancillarySize;      // Size of the ancillary data inside the data buffer

    VmbPixelFormat_t    pixelFormat;        // Pixel format of the image

    VmbUint32_t         width;              // Width of an image
    VmbUint32_t         height;             // Height of an image
    VmbUint32_t         offsetX;            // Horizontal offset of an image
    VmbUint32_t         offsetY;            // Vertical offset of an image

    VmbUint64_t         frameID;            // Unique ID of this frame in this stream
    VmbUint64_t         timestamp;          // Timestamp set by the camera
} VmbFrame_t;
```

It holds a pointer pointing to a buffer that will be used to pass image-data around. In older libaray versions, the user of the library would need to allocate this buffer and used this function to announce it to the library. Later they added functionality to only announce that you *want* a buffer and getting it allocated (and managed) by the library itself. In this case the lib would write the pointer into the array when calling this function.

From the first few comments I tend to think they kept the signature as is for compatibility and made some hacks in their implementation to actually achieve the described behaviour.

Comment: The argument declaration and the description seems to contradic each other. If `pFrame` is pointing to a `const` structure then the structure can't be changed.

Comment: You *can* pass the address of a non-const struct to the function. If so. the object can be modified (needs a cast, but it is doable).

Comment: @BoP It's also very bad style, and a good way to make bad and unmaintainable code.

Comment: I've added an edit containing some extra information towards Lundins question and also how I'd make sense of it with the first couple somments in mind.